# extend two lists and take median in one line

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to take the median of two concatenated lists, where one of the lists is the result of the numpy repeat function.

This code works fine:

```
from numpy import median, repeat
g = [4, 5, 6]
g.extend([i.item() for i in repeat(0, 10)])
median(g)
```

For some reason the above code fails if I try to do this in one line:

```
g = [4, 5, 6]
median(g.extend([i.item() for i in repeat(0, 10)]))
```

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

I really need to do this in one line. I tried using asarray but get the same error:

```
from numpy import asarray
g = [4, 5, 6]
median(asarray(g.extend([i.item() for i in repeat(0, 10)])))
```

Above, I use `item()` to convert the numpy type output of repeat back to regular python types.

Comment: My numpy skills are bad, but if `g.extend()` doesn't return `g`, you can't pass it into `median()` and get the same result as `median(g)`

Comment: Thanks, know of any workaround?

Comment: My turtle self made an attempt, but @sacuL beat me to it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `g.extend()` returns `None`, and not the extended list, you can use the `+` operator between lists instead:

```
>>> median(g + ([i.item() for i in repeat(0, 10)]))
0.0
# or, getting rid of the unnecessary list comprehension as per @xdhmoore's comment:
>>> median(g + repeat(0, 10).tolist())
```

Adding two lists together with `+` functionally does the same as `.extend()`, but not in place:

```
>>> g + ([i.item() for i in repeat(0, 10)])
[4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]


# vs:

>>> g = [4, 5, 6]

>>> g.extend([i.item() for i in repeat(0, 10)])

>>> g
[4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: I think you could also use `repeat(0, 10).tolist()` to make it more concise?

Comment: @xdhmoore, yup, that would be nicer! adding to my answer :)

Comment: Thanks, it's great